# Prompt user prior to installing R package

Tags: r, package, user-input, r-package

I have looked at the install.packages help files, Google, and Stack, but I don't see a way to prompt the user prior to installing a package.  Is there an install.packages option to require a user prompt asking if the user wants to install the package prior to actually installing the package?

In not possible using install.packages, is there another way to achieve this result?

Comment: I would think if they run the command `install.packages()` then chances are good they want to install a package. Same as if they typed `2+3` I'd assume they just want to add those numbers so there's no mechanism to "confirm" that's what they want before doing that. Is there a particular problem you are trying to avoid? It's not exactly easy to accidently run `install.packages`. You could write your own function that would require confirmation, but you would still need a way to get that to other people I suppose.

Comment: Hi MrFlick.  My notebook requires a lot of packages and I have a short script that checks if the packages are already installed and up to date on my collaborator's computer, and (now) double checks to make sure they actually want to install the required package.  I don't want to break anyone's setup.

Comment: Ah, that's an important piece of context that was missing from the original question.

Comment: Quite possibly true.  I was trying to keep the question as generic as possible while still being specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function menu() inside an if statement to make a simple confirmation mechanism. This will work:

```
package <- "foo"

if (menu(c("Yes", "No"),
         title= paste("Are you sure you want to install package", package)) == "1") {
    install.packages(package)
} else { print("Cancelling installation")}
```